# Strangely defined ball compact in $L^p(I)$ or not?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $I = (0, 1)$ and $1 \le p \le \infty$. Set$$B_p = \{u \in W^{1, p}(I) : \|u\|_{L^p(I)} + \|u'\|_{L^p(I)} \le 1\}.$$When $1 < p \le \infty$, does it necessarily follow that $B_p$ is compact in $L^p(I)$?

Comment: Do you know the Ascoli-Arzelà theorem? This is very similar.

Comment: The ball is not really strange, it is the unit ball in (one of the variants of) the $W^{1,p}$ norm. Thus the title should be $W^{1,p}$ unit ball compact in $L^p=W^{0,p}$. Which is equivalent to the embedding operator $W^{1,p}\to L^p$ being compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$B_p$ compact in $L^p$ $\Rightarrow$ $B_p$ closed in $L^p$ $\Rightarrow$ $B_p$ complete in $L^p$ $\Rightarrow$ $W^{1,p}(I)$ complete w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|_{L^p}$

So, $B_p$ isn't compact in $L^p$.

However, $B_p$ is relatively compact in $L^p$.